# I want a progressbar but get a spinner progressdialog

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog

I am using a public AsynTask to download data, and I am trying to show a progress bar which would show the download progress. I think I have the code right, but all I get is a spinner progressdialog. Am I missing something? Why isn't the progress bar showing up? Here is the code.
Thanks for any pointers.

```
public class FileDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>
{
private Context _appContext;
private HttpURLConnection _urlConn;
private ProgressDialog _progressDia = null;
private DialogInterface.OnCancelListener _progDiaCancelListener = new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
{
    /**
     * When the progress dialog is canceled, stop the GET request.
     */
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) 
    {
        FileDownloader.this.cancel(true);
    }
};

/**
 * Constructor.
 * @param appContext
 */
public FileDownloader(Context appContext)
{
    _appContext = appContext;
    _progressDia = new ProgressDialog(_appContext, ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    _progressDia.setMax(100);
    _progressDia.setTitle(_appContext.getString(R.string.diaHeader1));
    _progressDia.setMessage(_appContext.getString(R.string.diaBody1));
    _progressDia.setCancelable(true);
    _progressDia.setIndeterminate(false);
    _progressDia.setOnCancelListener(_progDiaCancelListener);
}

// Runs on the UI thread
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
         _progressDia.setProgress(0);
         _progressDia.show();                           
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... args) 
{
    String dloadURL = args[0],
           saveLoc = args[1];
            ...
            ...
        while((len = input.read(buf)) > 0)
        {
            output.write(buf, 0, len);
            total += len;
            publishProgress((int)total * 100/lenghtOfFile);
        }
            ...
            ...
    }
    catch(SocketTimeoutException ex)
    {   
    }
    finally
    {
         ...
}

// This is executed on main UI thread.
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
{
     _progressDia.setProgress(values[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() 
{
         ...
}

// This is executed on main UI thread.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
{
        removeProgressDialog();
        ...
}

    /**
     * Remove the message dialog, if still showing.
     */
    private void removeProgressDialog()
    {
        if(_progressDia != null && _progressDia.isShowing())
        _progressDia.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you forget to set `dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);`

See this example code that works me:

```
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Matching progress");
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialog.setMax(100);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
 */
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    return null;

}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    dialog.hide();
    dialog = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this works. Only thing I had to change is use the single parameter constructor and set the progress style.

Comment: Thanks, helped me too. My mistake was that I was calling `ProgressDialog.show(...);` and after that setting all other parameters

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you are using the two arg constructor for ProgressDialog, which the documentation suggests is for the Context (first arg) and the theme id (the second arg).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#ProgressDialog(android.content.Context, int)

So while you THINK you are setting the ProgressStyle to STYLE_HORIZONTAL, you are not doing that at all, you are setting the theme id to something that is likely not a valid theme id.

I would suggest using the one arg constructor that takes in a Context, and then do as Pentium10 suggests and call _progressDia.setProgressStyle(ProgressStyle.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

Comment: You are right - I thought that I am setting the style to horizontal by using the two param constructor, but that is not the case. Not sure what that is .... anyway, things are working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can also give it this tag in the xml file

style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"

Comment: a million ups for this. the gui editor labels it as horizontal when you create it but doesn't create it as a horizontal progress bar(this is a bug in eclipse adk)

Answer (score -1):

do entry of progress bar 
in your android project current intent XML  file as a progress bar

also check it after saving 
in R.java file for id of your progress bar

the intent should be called whenever download is started

like

startActivity(new Intent(this, Progress.class));